# applying a force to a rigid body

Tags: ros, gazebo, force

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I'm trying to write a controller for a robot that is modelled as a rigid body. In particular the robot is made by several link connected through fixed joints. I would like to apply a simple force along one of the axis to the main link of the robot. I tried to look at the erratic controller but i just found a way to apply velocity to the joints connected to the wheels. Is there a way to apply a force to a link?

thanks for your help!

EDIT: I'm working with gazebo and I would like to apply a force when a certain key is pushed (I already have implemented the teleoperation module). Is it possible to apply both an impulsive force and a continuos force?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11047/applying-a-force-to-a-rigid-body/) by [erpa](https://answers.ros.org/users/995/erpa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2011-08-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2011-08-29**:
Are you talking about Gazebo? If yes, you could add the Gazebo tag to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Assuming you are talking about Gazebo, you can apply a force to a body using this command on the command line:

```
rosservice call /gazebo/apply_body_wrench '{body_name: "object_1::object_1_base_link", reference_frame: "object_1::object_1_base_link", wrench: { force: { x: 0, y: 0, z: -20.0 } }, start_time: 0, duration: -1 }'
```

Of course, you can also call the `apply_body_wrench` service from a program.

**Edit:** Another alternative is accessing the body from a Gazebo plugin. I haven't done that yet, but I think it should run along these lines:

- you get a Gazebo [Model](http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/doc/Gazebo-manual-svn-html/classgazebo_1_1Model.html) object in the constructor of your controller
- use `Model->GetBody(const std::string &name)` to get the body representing your link by name
- use `Body->SetForce(const Vector3 &force)` to apply the force

I also found looking at [turtlebot_gazebo_plugins](http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_gazebo_plugins) as an example for some of these steps very helpful.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2011-08-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [erpa](https://answers.ros.org/users/995/erpa/) on 2011-08-31**:
Solved! To apply the force in the object reference frame first you have to get the pose of the object itself with GetWorldPose() and rotate the force vector accordingly ( i used RotateVector() ), last you can apply the force to the object. thanks again for help.

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2011-08-30**:
That could be true. I don't know if there's a better way, but perhaps you have to rotate the force vector yourself (grep for "rotate" in gazebo_plugins to see some examples).

**Comment by [erpa](https://answers.ros.org/users/995/erpa/) on 2011-08-30**:
thanks, it's exactly what i was looking for! Just one last question, trying to run my simulation it appears that the force is applied using world reference frame instead then body frame, am i mistaken? I will also take a look at turtlebot_gazebo_plugins as soon as it finish the download :D

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2011-08-30**:
Okay, I've edited my answer to that effect.

**Comment by [erpa](https://answers.ros.org/users/995/erpa/) on 2011-08-30**:
hi, thanks for answering! yes i work with gazebo (i edited both the tags and the question for future reference) but rather then calling rosservice through a new terminal i would like to apply it in my controller so i was looking for the cpp function. i'm sorry if my question was missleading.